# What are the main differences between map() and sapply() function?

Tags: r, data-science

I usually use `sapply()` function for the functions I have already created. However, I create functions inside `map()` functions. I don't know why I am doing that but I realized that I don't know the differences between these two functions.

Comment: Here is a nice article on the topic: https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/bk01_base-functions.html#lapply()_vs_purrr::map()